# Using SetInformationJobObject to limit the process memory using Jobs

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to write a simple program that accepts a process ID and sets the limit of a process memory by using Jobs.

It does not return an error, but when `SetInformationJobObject()` is called after `AssignProcessToJobObject()`, it does not seem to apply.

I am using `testlimit64.exe -d 2024 -c 1`  from the SysInternals suite to test this program out. I can confirm the Job has been attached to a process, because when I call `TerminateJobObject()` the PID I attached the Job exits when `TerminateJobObject()` is called.

Below is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    DWORD pid;
    HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);
    printf("Type in PID\n");
    scanf_s("%u",&pid);
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_SET_QUOTA | PROCESS_TERMINATE,FALSE, pid);

    if (!hJob) {
        printf("Failed to create job, GetLastError() = %d\n",GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!hProc) {
        printf("Failed to OpenProcess, GetLastError() = %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob,hProc)) {
        printf("Failed to AssignProcessToJobObject, GetLastError() = %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION info;
    info.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY;
    info.JobMemoryLimit = 536870912;//trying to set it to 512 MB

    if (!SetInformationJobObject(hJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &info, sizeof(info))) {
        printf("Failed to SetInformationJobObject, GetLastError() = %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("The process %d has it's memory restricted!!!\n, press ENTER to close program",pid);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }

    TerminateJobObject(hJob, 0);
    CloseHandle(hJob);
    CloseHandle(hProc);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have also tried to set the `JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED` info struct to different limitflags to see if makes a difference, but doing the following did not help:

```
info.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY;
info.ProcessMemoryLimit = 536870912;//trying to set it to 512 MB
```

Comment: Are you adding the testlimit64 process to the job *before* it allocates the memory?

Comment: @joshpoley I just attached the Job handle to the command prompt where I have testlimit allocating memory.  It seems to work now when I call testlimit on the command prompt where I have a Job memory limit running; testlimit does not work for memory allocations above 512mB. What is weird is I have been able to lower CPU priority, and even deny clipboard access to PID's I attach my job. to in realtime. I guess for this one, it only works when the Job is attached to the PID prior to allocating memory.

Comment: You can't limit already allocated memory, the limitation is enforced at allocation time.

Comment: That's good to know, I will leave this question here regardless just in case anybody else is wondering. I wish I could mark your comment as the resolving question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @joshpoley said,

> You can't limit already allocated memory, the limitation is enforced
> at allocation time.

Here is the confirmation of [AssignProcessToJobObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-assignprocesstojobobject#remarks) document,

> Memory operations performed by a process associated with a job that
> has a memory limit are subject to the memory limit. **Memory operations
> performed by the process before it was associated with the job are not
> examined by AssignProcessToJobObject**.